# Weather station database design, receiving every second sensor data

Tags: asp.net, sql, database, weather

If I store the data every second, the database will grow rapidly. I need to have less detail of measurements of a few weeks/months back. An average would be enough. I have 5 sensors: wind speed, wind direction, temperature, light and rain. How would I design my database?

Comment: Is this homework? No problem helping with homework, but if it is you'll do better if you show what you have so far and ask for a review of that or specific questions about aspects. The homework is for your benefit.

Comment: You might get more help if you post a design you have worked on and ask for people to review it, rather than just asking others to do the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'd design a table for the current data and then tables with aggregated data. Every once in a while (maybe a nighly/weekly/monthly run) I'd aggregate the data, write it to the tables and delete it from the current data.

I'd have exactly the same table (fields: measurement id, wind speed, wind direction, temperature, light and rain, timestamp) for each aggregation level I need.

1. measurements_weekly
2. measurements_daily_average
3. measurements_weekly_average
4. measurements_monthly_average
5. measurements_yearly_average

This has several advantages: 
The data can be managed separately (Backup/detailed reports etc.).
You just need one aggregation procedure for all aggregation levels and run it with different timespans and tables as arguments. Queries on any table and thus analysis will be fast and performant.

If you dislike the seemingly redundant structures, two tables can be enough as well:
one for the measurements and one for the aggregated measurements, which must then include a timespan. But this approach will introduce complexity to your aggregation routines and any analysis, thus I would not use it.